# Spring Integration: Content based router with default output channel?

Tags: java, spring, routes, spring-integration

I'd like use Spring Integration to implement a content based router that uses a default output channel if the expression value doesn't match any of the mappings. Here's my bean definition:

```
<int:router input-channel="channel_in" default-output-channel="channel_default" expression="payload.name">
    <int:mapping value="foo" channel="channel_one" />
    <int:mapping value="bar" channel="channel_two" />
```

However, it seems the default output channel is never used. If the expression evaluates to e.g. 'baz', the router seems to be looking for a channel named 'baz', instead of routing to the 'channel_default' channel:

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'baz'
  Caused by: org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: 
    failed to look up MessageChannel bean with name 'baz'
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No bean named 'baz' is defined
```

Is what I want at all possible using the XML namespace, or do I need to code up my own implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that all I had to to to make this work was to set the router's ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures attribute to false:

```
<int:router input-channel="channel_in" default-output-channel="channel_default" 
  expression="payload.name" ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures="true">
    <int:mapping value="foo" channel="channel_one" />
    <int:mapping value="bar" channel="channel_two" />
</int:router>
```

I thought I had tried that before, but I seems I didn't.

Comment: If you're reading this for Spring Integration 2.1+, ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures has been dropped. You can get the same effect by useing resolution-required="false". See http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#2.1-router-standardization

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/router.html):

> As of Spring Integration 2.1, router parameters have been more
> standardized across all router implementations. Consequently, a few
> minor changes may break older Spring Integration based applications.
>
> Since Spring Integration 2.1, the
> `ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures` attribute is removed in favor
> of consolidating its behavior with the `resolution-required` attribute.
> Also, the resolution-required attribute now defaults to `true`.
>
> Prior to these changes, the `resolution-required` attribute defaulted to
> `false`, causing messages to be silently dropped when no channel was
> resolved and no `default-output-channel` was set. The new behavior
> requires at least one resolved channel and, by default, throws a
> `MessageDeliveryException` if no channel was determined (or an attempt
> to send was not successful).
>
> If you do desire to drop messages silently, you can set
> `default-output-channel="nullChannel"`.

And if you are using Java DSL, the configuration may looks like this:

```java
IntegrationFlows.from("process")
        .<JobExecution, String>route(m -> m.getExitStatus().getExitCode(),
                m -> m.channelMapping(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode(), "succeed")
                        .defaultOutputChannel("failed")
                        .resolutionRequired(false))
        .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using for Spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then **resolution-required="false"** is required instead of ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures.

```
<int:router input-channel="channel_in" default-output-channel="channel_default" 
  expression="payload.name" resolution-required="false">
    <int:mapping value="foo" channel="channel_one" />
    <int:mapping value="bar" channel="channel_two" />
</int:router>
```